# log4j2.xml creates file, but does not output anything in the file

Tags: java, xml, log4j2

I have the a log4j2.xml file and a class and am trying to test logging using the two, but am unable to print to my outputted file. My log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="C:\Tomcat\logs\all.log" immediateFlush="false"      
    append="false">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - 
    %msg%n"/>
    </File>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="debug">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info" />
        <AppenderRef ref="MyFile" level="info"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My program is the following code:

```
public class LoggingTest {

Logger testLog = LogManager.getLogger("Log_File");


public String setString(String test)
{   
    if (test=="warn")
    {
        testLog.warn("Error");
        return "no";
    }
    else
        testLog.info("Complete");
    return "yes";
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoggingTest a=new LoggingTest();
    System.out.println(a.setString("warn"));
    }
}
```

My logging prints to console no problem, and creates the log file in the correct location, but no text is written to the log file. What could possibly be causing this? Something related to my log4j2.xml file?

Comment: Don't compare Strings with ==, use equals method.

Comment: Why do you have immediateFlush="false"? This is what probably causing the problem since log output is not written to the file right away...

Comment: @user1071777 I don't think that's relevant to my question. Considering this is a simple test class, I don't care about my comparisons.

Comment: @dimoniy That did it, submit as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @antihero989 done, with explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `immediateFlush="false"` set up for your appender. What that means is that log output will not be added to the file immediately but rather be added to a buffer where it would sit waiting for buffer to fill up. Once the buffer fills up the data will be written to the file in one big swoop. The advantage of this method is that it will be faster than multiple small file writes. One disadvantage that you already experiencing is that you cannot monitor your log in real time. Another thing to worry about is that if your application stops unexpectedly the log data in the buffer might be lost.